# Eliminating plumbing vent pipes

Tags: plumbing

Can you eliminate a vent through the roof using indoor cheater vents under the sinks including tub and shower

Answer (score 3):

Can you? Sure. Should you? Nope. It's probably not legal and there's a good chance you'll end up with a poop-smelling house and a completely explicable headache.

Comment: Could you reduce the number of roof penetrations by combining several vents into one larger vent in the attic?

Comment: In some cases, probably. Depends on distance, current usage, etc.